# Is there any difference between this selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I've inherited very messy jQuery code which I'm supposed to fix. There are some very interesting code lines :) but this one makes me wonder.

```
$("input[type=submit][id='Verifier']").addClass("bttnDisable stateDisable").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

is it any different from

```
$("#Verifier").addClass("bttnDisable stateDisable").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

There is no other element with such ID on the page so I find it rather useless. I think it might have some meaning if there was another element with the same ID (which is wrong AFAIK). Or does it have some other advantage of which I'm not aware? Also, isn't it slower?

Comment: You're right, it is one useless line.

Comment: when you have id (as id must be unique), then other jquery selector does not make any sense. `$("#Verifier")` is correct approach, though both selectors will do the same thing but later one is faster.

Comment: While you are at it, you might also change `.attr("disabled", "disabled")` to `.prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: indeed, an Id should only be once on the page, so the second code is perfectly fine if the rest of the page is fine as well. In case Verifier would be a class i would recomment using `input.Verifier[type=submit]` as selector. If its inplmented in jQuery, why not use it?

Comment: thanks for the `prop()` and class selector, this might come handy

Comment: In theory you can have this JS code attached to other pages and on those other pages there might be element with id 'Verifier'. In this case first query will select only if this element is also a submit button, while second will select all Verifiers on all pages.

Comment: @Volvox [If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: @Grundy but if 'Verifier' is on submit button on Register Page and other 'Verifier' is a DIV on other page and both pages use this same JS file, then `input[type=submit][id='Verifier']` will select only submit button on Register Page and `#Verifier` will select both of them (as they are not on this same page)

Comment: @Volvox oooh, you right, i'm little confused :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `id` should be unique in a document, chaining other selectors with an id to target an element seems to be useless.

*is it any different?*

Yes, The id selector will use the native `document.getElementById` method and will be way faster than the chained one.